# Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Пишу авторизацию через ВК на React Native. Когда нажимаю на кнопку "Войти с помощью ВКонтакте" ловлю ошибку.
[image: ошибка]

Сама по себе функциональность работает, данные пользователя от ВК я получаю, но я хочу это делать именно при нажатии на кнопку авторизации, а с кнопкой что-то не то.

Мой код:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';
import * as AuthSession from 'expo-auth-session';

const App = () => {

    const [hasError, setErrors] = useState(false);
    const [userData, setState] = useState({});

    useEffect(() => {
        async function fetchData(e) {
            e.preventDefault()
            let result = await AuthSession.startAsync({
                authUrl: 'https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id=7563861&display=mobile&redirect_uri=https://auth.expo.io/@laneboyandrew/beautifulPlaces&response_type=token&v=5.92',
            });
            if (result.type === 'success') {
                const res = await fetch('https://api.vk.com/method/users.get?v=5.92&access_token=' + result.params.access_token);
                res
                    .json()
                    .then(res => setState(res))
                    .catch(err => setErrors(err));
            }
        }
        fetchData();
    });
    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
        container: {
            flex: 1,
            backgroundColor: '#e9ebee',
            alignItems: 'center',
            justifyContent: 'center',
        },
        loginBtn: {
            backgroundColor: '#4267b2',
            paddingVertical: 10,
            paddingHorizontal: 20,
            borderRadius: 20
        },
        logoutBtn: {
            backgroundColor: 'grey',
            paddingVertical: 10,
            paddingHorizontal: 20,
            borderRadius: 20,
            position: "absolute",
            bottom: 0
        },
    });
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.loginBtn} onPress={App}>
                <Text style={{color: "#fff"}}>Войти с помощью ВКонтакте</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    );
};
export default App;
```

Comment: что такое `await AuthSession.startAsync`?

Comment: AuthSession is the easiest way to add web browser based authentication (for example, browser-based OAuth flows) to your app, built on top of WebBrowser, Crypto, and Random. Здесь подробное описание - https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/auth-session/ Я использую expo.

Comment: Вы понимаете что у Вас написано? Я не совсем. Вы установили компонент в качестве обработчика события? А так можно?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так всё работает.

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {Button, StyleSheet, View} from "react-native";
import * as AuthSession from "expo-auth-session";
import Location from "./Location";

const VkAuthorize = (props) => {
const [hasError, setErrors] = useState(false);
    const [userData, setState] = useState({});
    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
        container: {
            flex: 1,
            backgroundColor: '#e9ebee',
            alignItems: 'center',
            justifyContent: 'center',
        },
        loginBtn: {
            backgroundColor: '#4267b2',
            paddingVertical: 10,
            paddingHorizontal: 20,
            borderRadius: 20
        },
        logoutBtn: {
            backgroundColor: 'grey',
            paddingVertical: 10,
            paddingHorizontal: 20,
            borderRadius: 20,
            position: "absolute",
            bottom: 0
        },
    });
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Button style={styles.loginBtn} onPress={
                async function fetchData(e) {
                    e.preventDefault()
                    let result = await AuthSession.startAsync({
                        authUrl: 'https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id=7563861&display=mobile&redirect_uri=https://auth.expo.io/@laneboyandrew/beautifulPlaces&response_type=token&v=5.92',
                    });
                    console.log(result)
                    if (result.type === 'success') {
                        const res = await fetch('https://api.vk.com/method/users.get?v=5.92&access_token=' + result.params.access_token);
                        res
                            .json()
                            .then(res => props.setState(res))
                            .catch(err => props.setErrors(err));
                    }
                }
            } title="Войти через ВКонтакте"/>
        </View>
    );
}
export default VkAuthorize
```

Answer (score 0):

`onPress={App}` должен быть чем-то другим

Comment: Возможно необходимо вызывать вместо функции App, функцию fetchData которая внтури useEffect? Но она недоступна.

Comment: a зачем она в useEffect?